# Two Divs next to each other, that then stack with responsive change

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to achieve something that I am sure should be easier than I am making it!

I am using the Skeleton responsive framework, and have been fine up until now.

Here is a diagram of what I want to achieve.

[image: Diagram showing what I div layout]

This will be placed within a column. Once that columns reduces in size, I would like it to stack the divs as per the second example in the diagram. I've tried a few different ways, but keep getting it wrong.

I am pretty new to HTML/CSS so any help is appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: are u trying to work for mobile version, then u should use Bootstrap or media queries or both u can use .

Comment: Give `float: left` to each element and add `width` to parent of these elements

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use CSS3 **media query** for this. Write like this:

**CSS**

```
.wrapper { 
  border : 2px solid #000; 
  overflow:hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
}
#one {
  background-color: gray;
  float:left; 
  margin-right:20px;
  width:140px;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
}
#two { 
  background-color: white;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px;
  border:2px dashed #ccc;
  min-height:170px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   #one { 
    float: none;
    margin-right:0;
    width:auto;
    border:0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;    
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Check this for more http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/1/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, Internet went down whilst checking this out yesterday! Once it's back up ill respond further, but this one looks great, and from the little time I got to play with it, seems like it will do the job!

Comment: Hope this is OK, to add this to the initial question.
I have altered the divs slightly to suit my design.
Fiddle here [http://jsfiddle.net/JxHnE/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/JxHnE/1/)

I want the image within the "photo" div to fill the photo div at all times, but to keep its aspect ratio. The main area it breaks is when the divs are made narrower, the title breaks to three lines, and you end of with whitespace below the image. Any idea how I can stop this?

Comment: How to achieve it with Bootstrap/Foundation frameworks?

Comment: Thank you very much, this reply is really well explained

Answer (score 17):

today this kind of thing can be done by using `display:flex;`

https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/1435/

html:

```
  <div class="container flex-direction">
      <div class="div1">
        <span>Div One</span>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <span>Div Two</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.container{
  display:inline-flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.flex-direction{
  flex-direction:row;
}
.div1{
  border-right:1px solid black;
  background-color:#727272;
  width:165px;
  height:132px;
}

.div2{
  background-color:#fff;
  width:314px;
  height:132px;
}

span{
  font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: block;
    line-height: 132px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .flex-direction{
  flex-direction:column;
  }
.div1{
  width:202px;
  height:131px;
  border-right:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  }
  .div2{
    width:202px;
    height:107px;
  }
  .div2 span{
    line-height:107px;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a very simple and elegant solution. I used it for my website. And it's working well. I thought "flex" thing was only for mobile apps (React Native). I didn't know you could use that for html websites as well. Thank you very much for the solution.

Answer (score 9):

Floating div's will help what your trying to achieve.

[**Example**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/aluesulk)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content1 content">
</div>
<div class="content2 content">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
width:100%;
height:200px;
background-color:grey;
}
.content{
float:left;
height:30px;
}
.content1{
background-color:blue;
width:300px;
}
.content2{
width:200px;
background-color:green;
}
```

Zoom in the page to see the effects.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is true for fixed width, but for fluid layout its not responsive for example 50% by 50%

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never!

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With a mediaquery based on a `min-width` you could achieve something like http://jsbin.com/aruyiq/1/edit

CSS

```
.wrapper { 
  border : 2px dotted #ccc; padding: 2px; 
}

.wrapper div {
   width: 100%; 
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
#one { background-color: gray; }
#two { background-color: white; }

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .wrapper {
      height: auto; overflow: hidden; // clearing 
   }
   #one { width: 200px; float: left; }
   #two { margin-left: 200px; }
}
```

In my example the breakpoint is `600px` but you could adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent{
    width: 400px;
    background: red;
}
.child{
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    background:green;
    height: 100px;
}
```

This is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/). Change child `width` to more then `200px` and they will stack.

Comment: by far the simplest solution. width and float : left

Comment: this was the most elegant solution for my problem

Comment: Just tried out the JSFiddle and those two `child` elements just squish, they don't stack.

Comment: `Change child width to more then 200px and they will stack.` - did you change `child` width? By the way this answer is 8 years old, there are better solutions nowadays ;)

Comment: Just, gave it a shot at 500, 900, 9000, all the same squish or just going offscreen.