# replace <td> with <tr> depending on browser width

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have a table in html, it has two cells. I would like for these cells, depending on the width of the browser, to be arranged either vertically or horizontally.

I have tried looking for a DOM function to get the job done, but came up with no solution so far.

Comment: You mean a responsive table?

Comment: You would need *both* tags to construct a valid `<table>`

Comment: Are you trying to use the table to format your page layout? Because if so, you shouldn't and should look at using the proper markup.

Comment: A table with just two cells? Is it presenting tabular data? If not, which is likely, I'd suggest `div`'s instead.

Comment: @ParagTyagi yes, something like that

Comment: Probably table is not the best element for this scenario. A pair of DIVs would work better

Comment: Try looking up responsive design, you should be using divs rather than tables.

Comment: You can use a responsive grid system like the one implemented in bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Comment: Try using bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/. It has everything.

Comment: @Jeroen Tables are purposed to present tabular data. If you can wrap your table presentation from two cells to two rows, you actually don't need a table. However, techically very interesting question, +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are bad juju for this exact reason. You should switch to a responsive layout. There are numerous libraries for this purpose; here are two that I have used extensively: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/, http://getbootstrap.com/.

If you're not looking to use a library, check the [possible dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436800/two-divs-next-to-each-other-that-then-stack-with-responsive-change)

Here's how I would do it in bootstrap:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            Half the page
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            Other half
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- [Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4370/)

Comment: This is indeed what is want for my responsive part. But my ordinary page should have the two next to each other (like in a table). Please help me with that.

Ah I see your link, now, that's it, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to assist; happy coding! You may want to center the div contents to make it look a bit better. I recommend taking a look at the bootstrap docs, they have a lot of amazing helper classes

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a table. Use `div`'s or some other non-table element, styled as an `inline-block` with a fixed width.

```
<style type='text/css'>
  .cell {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px; /* or whatever */
  }
</style>

<div class='cell'>something</div>
<div class='cell'>else</div>
```

If that doesn't suit you, start looking for other [responsive design strategies](https://www.google.com/#q=responsive+design&safe=off).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bootstrap` responsive tables for this.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
   ...
   </table>
</div>
```

Just add plugin, add simple code like above and voila.