# Divs in one line with dynamic width (justify)

Tags: html, css

I have a container which has left and right padding. Inside this container are two divs which should be side by side with a space between. Now because this space is fix but the site is responsive, the two text-divs must have a dynamic width. This is the reason why I can't use %-width.

I thought with `text-align: justify` it will work, but it doesn't.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qGw48/

Here the JSFiddle how it should look like: http://jsfiddle.net/4ekSm/ (it only works because of the %-widths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change:

div#container > div {

display: inline-block;

}

to:

```
div#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ekSm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done fairly easily if you make the width value take into account the padding. So I'm using the style:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qGw48/1/

This means that when you set a width then the padding will be included in that value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this http://jsfiddle.net/cUCvY/1/

I think It solves what your looking for

[Two Divs next to each other, that then stack with responsive change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436800/two-divs-next-to-each-other-that-then-stack-with-responsive-change)

you could add some margin to one of the boxes ie

```
  .left{
   margin-right: 5px; 
  }
```

Comment: But the space between is fix in px