# Different top margin in three divs with min-height using css queries (responsive)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I made these divs responsive following directions from 
 [another topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436800/two-divs-next-to-each-other-that-then-stack-with-responsive-change).

It works just fine, but I want to vertically align the the black divs in the second div and not to the "popular" div.

I can't vertically align bottom because the height of these boxes will not have the same height (in the list there will be more than 3 things). So what do you suggest?

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="website-pricing">
        <div class="website-pricing-top" style="border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; !important cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location='#';     padding-top:5px; !important">
            <!--#333333-->
            <!--top div-->
             <h2 style="color:#FFFFFF;"><br><center>Header <br>1</center></h2>
 <span class="website-pricing-top-details-mid" style="color:#24FF00;">
      <!--details mid-->
    </span>

            <p class="website-pricing-top-details-bot">
                <!--details bot-->Details details details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="website-pricing-bot">
            <!--#F7F7F7-->
            <!--bot div-->
            <ul class="pricing-list-ul" style="margin:0; padding:20px;">
                <li class="pricing-list-li" style="padding:10px;">first</li>
                <li class="pricing-list-li" style="margin:0; padding:10px;">second</li>
                <li class="pricing-list-li">third</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pricing-bot-banner-details" style="padding:2px;  height:50px; background:#89C02A; border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; cursor:pointer; onclick= window.location='#'" ;>
                <p style="text-align:center; color:black;"><b>more</b>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="website-pricing">
        <div class="website-prising-popular" style="min-height:50px height:50px">
            <!--popular #77338A / white font or #89C02A / black font-->Popular</div>
        <div class="website-pricing-top" style="border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location='http://www.blb.gr/kostologisi/web-site-static-build';">
            <!--#333333-->
            <!--top div-->
                <h2 style="color:#FFFFFF;"><br><center>Header <br>1</center></h2>
 <span class="website-pricing-top-details-mid" style="color:#24FF00;">
      <!--details mid-->
    </span>

            <p class="website-pricing-top-details-bot">
                <!--details bot-->Details details details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="website-pricing-bot">
            <!--#F7F7F7-->
            <!--bot div-->
            <ul class="pricing-list-ul" style="margin:0; padding:20px;">
                <li class="pricing-list-li" style="padding:10px;">first</li>
                <li class="pricing-list-li" style="margin:0; padding:10px;">second</li>
                <li class="pricing-list-li">third</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pricing-bot-banner-details" style="padding:2px;  height:50px; background:#89C02A; border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; cursor:pointer; onclick= window.location='#'" ;>
                <p style="text-align:center; color:black;"><b>more</b>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="website-pricing">
        <div class="website-pricing-top" style="border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location='#';">
            <!--#333333-->
            <!--top div-->
             <h2 style="color:#FFFFFF;"><br><center>Header <br>1</center></h2>
 <span class="website-pricing-top-details-mid" style="color:#24FF00;">
      <!--details mid-->
    </span>

            <p class="website-pricing-top-details-bot">
                <!--details bot-->Details details details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="website-pricing-bot">
            <!--#F7F7F7-->
            <!--bot div-->
            <ul class="pricing-list-ul" style="margin:0; padding:20px;">
                <li class="pricing-list-li" style="padding:10px;">first</li>
                <li class="pricing-list-li" style="margin:0; padding:10px;">second</li>
                <li class="pricing-list-li">third</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pricing-bot-banner-details" style="padding:2px;  height:50px; background:#89C02A; border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px; cursor:pointer; onclick= window.location='#'" ;>
                <p style="text-align:center; color:black;"><b>more</b>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .wrapper {
    border : 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper div {
    min-height: 50px;
}
.website-pricing {
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-right:70px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    min-height:200px;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:25%;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
.website-prising-popular {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    color:white;
    background-color:#89C02A;
    font-style:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin:0 0 5 0 px;
    padding:3 0 3 0;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
.website-pricing-top {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    background-color:#1C1C1C;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.website-pricing-top-details-mid {
    width:100%;
    font-size:3em;
}
.website-pricing-bot {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    font-size:12px;
    min-height: auto;
    height:auto;
}
.pricing-list-ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
}
.pricing-list-li {
    padding:10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #website-pricing {
        float: none;
        margin-right:0;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        border:0;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arteewtf/7yexw8uf/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: thanks for providing the fiddle but could also place the code in your question and then you can fix the link to the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7yexw8uf/2/

Use:

```
 position:absolute;
```

for the .website-prising-popular then addd position:relative, NOT overflow:hidden to .website-pricing and give them same margin-top as the "popular" negative top value)

Comment: When I give negative top value, it does align, but it also "cuts" the boxes on the top, so you can't see the radius and the word "popular".

Comment: if the jsfiddel works I'm afraid I would need to see more of your code to see why it is not working... probably something about the parents of "wrapper"

Answer (score 0):

I did what @Alvaro Menéndez said with the overflow and the position. I also gave inline negative margin-top value to the .website-pricing and added overflow:hidden; min and max-width to .wrapper div and it worked.

I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arteewtf/7yexw8uf/)
 in case anyone is interested.

Here is the new CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border : 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper div {
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:200px;
    max-width:25%;
}
.website-pricing {
    posotion:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:70px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    min-height:200px;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
.website-prising-popular {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    background-color:#89C02A;
    font-style:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin:0 0 5 0 px;
    padding:3 0 3 0;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width:200px;
}
.website-pricing-top {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    background-color:#1C1C1C;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.website-pricing-top-details-mid {
    width:100%;
    font-size:3em;
}
.website-pricing-bot {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#F7F7F7;
    color:black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    font-size:12px;
    min-height: auto;
    height:auto;
}
.pricing-list-ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
}
.pricing-list-li {
    padding:10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #website-pricing {
        float: none;
        margin-right:0;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        border:0;
    }
}
```