# 2 divs side by side that remain centered when screen is too small to fit them both

Tags: css

I am trying to create a page with 2 divs side by side, that when the screen becomes too narrow to fit them both will put the second div below the first one, both centered on the screen. Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: consider using bootstrap framework

Comment: @geeksal seriously? You are suggesting using an entire library to position two divs? Bootstrap is not a substitute for learning to use CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Divs next to each other, that then stack with responsive change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436800/two-divs-next-to-each-other-that-then-stack-with-responsive-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple standard css. Place 2 div's inside another div. Center both of them and set the width to a `px` size of your choosing. The divs will each be next to each other centered and if you adjust the screen size to not fit them both on one line, one will go beneath the other, still centered.

In the example below, click "full page" and just adjust the size of the screen to see how it will go onto the same line/go to next line depending if it fits or not.

```css
#one, #two {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height:300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
<div id="one" align="center">things</div>
<div id="two" align="center">more things</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this fairly simple with very little code. Place the two divs in a container. add `display:inline-block;` attribute to both divs inside the container and they will stack upon certain widths. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lg06c1sb/