# Forcing elements to move when web page is viewed on smartphone

Tags: html

I have a webpage with 3 side by side `<span>` elements - each is 400px wide.

This looks fine on my laptop (and other browsers and resolutions etc.)

As expected, when I look on my smartphone, there is not enough room for all 3 elements, and 1 moves down to the next row. I would however like to force each element onto a new row when looking on a smartphone.

So on a computer I want the user to see:

```
X X X
```

and on a smartphone:

```
X
X
X
```

Instead of what I see now:

```
XX
X
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Divs next to each other, that then stack with responsive change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436800/two-divs-next-to-each-other-that-then-stack-with-responsive-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is! This is called [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). You can use [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to tell the browser to use different style rules depending on the screen dimensions and orientation.