# place an image and text side by side inside div

Tags: html, responsive-design

I want to place an image and some text describing it.
This should be responsive, i.e. img and text should be side-by-side in large screen and top-bottom on smaller screen. 
So, basically, before you tag, its exactly same as [Two Divs next to each other, that then stack with responsive change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436800/two-divs-next-to-each-other-that-then-stack-with-responsive-change)

But this is not working.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>Hello</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="groupi">
  <div id="one">
    <img src="hello.jpg" style="width:10vw"/>  </div>
  <div id="two">Hello World</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.groupi { 
  border : 2px solid #000; 
  overflow:hidden;
}
.gruopi div {
   min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
}
#one {
  float: left;
  padding-top:4vw; 
  margin-left:3vw; 
  margin-right: 1vw; 
  margin-bottom: 5vw; 
  width: 10vw;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
}
#two { 
  background-color: black;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:1vw;
  border:2vw dashed #ccc;
  min-height:2vw;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #two{
  }
}
```

I am very new, and some help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your second div element (#two) to stack when your viewpoint is less than 600px wide, you can add the following to your media query:

```
#one {
   float: none;
}
```

So your full media query is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #one{
    float: none;
  }
}
```