# Scale all element while the window size changes or accessed in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to achieve is that when the window size changes or accessed in mobile, the "calculator" should also resize so that is does not clip.

Here is the code:

```
<style>
.calcbg{
    width: 950px;
    height: 500px;
}
.bg-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#container { 
    width : 100%; 
    height : 300px; 
}
#input_box_1 { 
    margin-left:65px; 
    float : left; 
    width : 40%; 
    height : 390px; 
    background-color : #ee7e29; 
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#input_box_2 { 
    margin-left:60px; 
    float : left; 
    width : 40%; 
    height : 390px; 
    background-color : #ee7e29;
    border-radius: 25px; 
} 
#input_data_1 { 
    position : relative; 
    left : 5%; 
    top : 3%; 
    width : 90%; 
    height : 70px; 
    border-radius : 10px; 
    border : 0px; 
    text-align : center; 
    font-family : Arial; 
    font-size : 30px; 
    text-shadow : 1px 1px 2px gray; 
} 
#output_data_1 { 
    position : relative; 
    left : 5%; 
    top : 150px; 
    width : 90%; 
    height : 70px; 
    border-radius : 10px; 
    border : 0px; 
    text-align : center; 
    font-family : Arial; 
    font-size : 30px; 
        text-shadow : 1px 1px 2px gray; 
} 
#input_data_2 { 
    position : relative; 
    left : 5%; 
    top : 3%; 
    width : 90%; 
    height : 70px; 
    border-radius : 10px; 
    border : 0px; 
    text-align : center; 
    font-family : Arial; 
    font-size : 30px; 
    text-shadow : 1px 1px 2px gray; 
}
#output_data_2 { 
    position : relative; 
    left : 5%; 
    top : 150px; 
    width : 90%; 
    height : 70px; 
    border-radius : 10px; 
    border : 0px; 
    text-align : center; 
    font-family : Arial; 
    font-size : 30px; 
    text-shadow : 1px 1px 2px gray; 
}
#exec_calc { 
    position : absolute; 
    left : 50%; 
    width : 180px; 
    height : 180px; 
    margin-left : -90px; 
    margin-top:65px; 
    background-color : #f2c426; 
    color : white; 
    border-radius : 100px; 
    border : 5px solid white; 
    line-height : 8em; 
    text-align : center; 
    font-family : arial; 
    font-size : 21px; 
    font-weight : 900; 
    cursor : pointer; 
    transition : width 0.1s, height 0.1s, margin-left 0.1s, margin-top 0.1s, font-size 0.1s,     
    box-shadow 0.1s; 
    user-select : none; 
    -moz-user-select; 
}
#exec_calc:hover { 
    width : 184px; 
    height : 184px; 
    margin-left : -92px; 
    margin-top : 63px; 
    font-size : 22px; 
    box-shadow : 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
#exec_calc:active { 
    width : 180px; 
    height : 180px; 
    margin-top : 62px; 
    margin-left : -90px; 
    box-shadow : none; 
    transition : none; 
}

#le_prompt { 
    position : absolute; 
    left : 50%; width : 30%; 
    height : auto; 
    margin-left : -15%; 
    margin-top : -100px; 
    padding : 10px;  
    text-align : center; 
    background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); 
    font-family : arial; 
    font-size : 20px; color : white; 
    border-radius : 10px; 
    display : none; 
    opacity : 0; 
    transition : opacity 0.5s; 
    }

<div  style="margin:auto;" class="calcbg">
<br/></p>

<div style="text-align:center;font-size:3em;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;color: #000;"></div>
<div id="container" >

<br/>.</p>
<br/>.</p>
<br/>.</p>
<br/>.</p>
<div style="position:absolute;margin-top:-70px;margin-left:195px;"><img width="146" height="83" src="<source>" class="attachment-724x724" alt="rtbhd">
</div>
<div style="position:absolute;margin-top:-70px;margin-left:630px;">
<img width="135" height="81" src="<source>" class="attachment-724x724" alt="bsavings">
</div>
<div style="position : absolute; margin-top : 120px; margin-left : 600px;">
<img width="210" height="115" src="<source>" class="attachment-724x724" alt="1yr">
</div>
<div style="color: #ffF; font-size : 1.3em; font-weight : 900; position:absolute; margin-top : 130px; margin-left:220px; font-size : 30px;"></div>
<div style="color: #fff; font-size : 1.3em; font-weight : 900; position:absolute; margin-top : 130px; margin-left:663px; font-size : 30px;"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;margin-top:120px;margin-left:150px;">
<img width="210" height="115" src="http://www.treasury.gov.ph/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/coupon-2.png" class="attachment-724x724" alt="1yr">
</div>
<div id="input_box_1" >
<br/></p>
<div style="color : #FFF; font-weight : bold; position : absolute; margin-top : 10px; margin-left : 140px;display:inline;">PIID0321F092</div>
<p><br/></p>
<p><input style="margin-top : 40px;" id="input_data_1" type="text"  placeholder="Investment Amount"/><br/><br />
<input id="output_data_1" type="text" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Return"/></div>
<div id="input_box_2" >
<div style="color : #FFF; font-weight : bold; position : absolute; margin-top : 10px; margin-left : 150px;"></div>
<p><br/><br />
<input style="margin-top:40px;" id="input_data_2" type="text" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Investment Amount"/><br/></p>
<p><input style="margin-top:20px;"id="output_data_2" type="text" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Return"/></div>
</div>
<div id="le_prompt"></div>
<div id="exec_calc">CALCULATE</div>
</div>
```

Here is the image:
[image]

This chunk is embedded in a web page.

I know about the concept of percentage but I want to know if there is another way like wrap this entire code into a div? or something so that the only thing that I will resize is the wrapper. Is there a possible way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the right element stack under the left element? If so then you can look at this answer: [Two Divs next to each other, that then stack with responsive change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436800/two-divs-next-to-each-other-that-then-stack-with-responsive-change)

You can also define your mobile responsive CSS @media Rule to show how your designs should be depicted on different screen sizes:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Depending if the occasion calls for it, I will also listen for the window resize event in JS and then I'd re-render the wrapper. window.addEventListener('resize', () => {});. But given your case I'd say that using css is definitely the best way to solve this problem.